# How to pass arguments into function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following function in nodejs, res.execSync takes in multiple parameters as detailed here:
https://github.com/xdenser/node-firebird-libfbclient

> function execSync(param1, param2, ..., paramN); 
>   
> param1, param2, ...,
>   paramN - parameters of prepared statement in the same order as in SQL
>   and with appropriate types.

```
function test(sql, callback)
{
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
  res.execSync(args);
}

test('test', function() {}, "param1", "param2", "param3");
```

Error: Expecting String as argument #1.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mean:

```
function test(sql, callback)
{
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  res.execSync.apply(res, args);
}

test('test', function() {}, "param1", "param2", "param3");
```

Answer (score 1):

`args` is an array. You need to use the `apply` method to unpack it into separate arguments.

```
res.execSync.apply(res, args);
```

It works just like `call` but receiving an array intead of the usual arguments list.

---

BTW, you can pass range arguments to slice. This means that there is a shorter way to write  your first line:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```